# How to return a Result<T, ParseIntError>?

Tags: rust, error-handling

I want a function to take in a reference to input and return a value if the input is valid or an error if its invalid. Here's my attempt but I get an error:

```rust
use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn get_fourth(input: &Vec<i32>) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let q = match input.get(4) {
        Some(v) => v,
        _ => return Err(ParseIntError {kind: ParseIntError} )
    };
    Ok(*q)
}

fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec![9, 0, 10];
    let fourth = get_fourth(&my_vec);
}
```

```
error[E0423]: expected value, found struct `ParseIntError`
 --> src/main.rs:6:46
  |
6 |         _ => return Err(ParseIntError {kind: ParseIntError} )
  |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
help: use struct literal syntax instead
  |
6 |         _ => return Err(ParseIntError {kind: ParseIntError { kind: val }} )
  |                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`ParseIntError` is just temporary for my testing. How can I return an error? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning an error just fine, its your use of `ParseIntError` that is messed up. You cannot construct an instance of `ParseIntError` yourself because its fields are private and there's no public constructing function.

> `ParseIntError` is just temporary for my testing.

Well go ahead and make your own non-temporary error and you'll see the rest of your code works:

```
struct LengthError;

fn get_fourth(input: &Vec<i32>) -> Result<i32, LengthError> {
    let q = match input.get(4) {
        Some(v) => v,
        _ => return Err(LengthError)
    };
    Ok(*q)
}
```

Comment: Oh! I got it. Regarding `struct LengthError;`. We only can use `struct`, instead of `enum` in rust, right!

Comment: @curlywei Not sure how you came to understand *that* from my answer, an `enum` can be used as an error just fine. I just provided the simplest dummy type to use as an error.

Comment: OK! I solved my problem. `std::num::ParseFloatError` seems to adopt this solution. (similar to your answer)